# Swift - Issues with setting background image in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, background, uiimageview

I have created a `UIScrollView` and added `UILabels` and `UIButtons`.  I then have created a `UIImageView` and added it to the my `UIScrollView`.  I have used the following code to set the `UIImageView` to the background of my `UIScrollView`.

```
        let paperImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "White Notebook Paper.png"))
        paperImageView.frame = CGRect(x: -60, y: -60, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width + 60, height: currentY + 60)
        scrollView.addSubview(paperImageView)
        scrollView.sendSubview(toBack: paperImageView)
```

As you can see in the following screenshot, by `UIImageView` is distorted.

[image]

The background image supposed to look like notebook paper.  As you can see, the spacing of the lines becomes wider the lower you go in the `UIScrollView`.  Thanks for taking the time to share your thoughts.

Comment: try changing content mode of imageview

Comment: @Jay Taylor , your image is average distribution of these lines?

Comment: @Jay Taylor , `currentY` is how much?

Comment: @Vinodh  Yep!!  That did the trick!!  Thanks!!

Comment: @aircraft  You are correct with the average distribution.  I just forgot the address the content mode.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to change the content mode of the image view.

```
paperImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```